# SQL Server : DATEADD 29 February not return 30,31 January

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, datediff, dateadd

I'm working in SQL Server 2014 and need calculate exactly one month previous from a SQL Server `DateTime`, but I'm unable figure out how to use `DATEADD` correctly.

Examples:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -1, '20200229')
```

returns `2020-01-29`.

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -1, '20200301')
```

returns `2020-02-01`.

But in this second statement, I would like to get `2020-01-30` and `2020-01-31`

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: This seem ok, 1 month before march first, is february first.

Comment: You say *`Dateadd` is not working correctly*. Can you please refer to a source that subsantiates your claim?

Comment: Hmm, I think he wants the last day of previous month by being on the last day of current month.

Comment: That code and the input/output look OK to me. It would be rather unexpected that subtracting 1 month from `29 february` would return `31 january`.

Comment: Define one month? X number of days or weeks? Obviously the same "day" in the month wouldn't count. For the first day of the month and last day of the month one could draw logical conclusions, but what about other days in the month. What would be "one month" from them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you want end of previous month, in that case add `EOMONTH()` to your script which goes as follows

```
Select EOMONTH( DATEADD(MONTH,-1,'20200229'));

Select EOMONTH( DATEADD(MONTH,-1,'20200301'));
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

If the following are true:

- datepart is month the date month has more days than the return month
- the date day does not exist in the return month

Then, DATEADD returns the last day of the return month.

For example, September has 30 (thirty) days; therefore, these statements return 2006-09-30 00:00:00.000:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, '20060830');
SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, '20060831');
```

Answer (score 0):

2020 is a Leap Year. Most of the time your `2/29` would not work anyway.
Also there is no `2/30 & 2/31` so `1/30 & 1/31` would not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Use the EOMONTH() function with the optional second parameter, which is an int and is the number of months difference to the date:

```
select eomonth('2020-02-29', -1);
```

Returns:

```
2020-01-31
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(MONTH, -1, '20200229')), DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, -2, '20200301')) + 1, 0))
```